# Determine the asymptotic distribution $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta) $ for trinomial distribution over the group sizes $(x,y,z)$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

A random sample of $n$ individuals are classified into three groups, with probabilities $\theta^2$, $2\theta(1-\theta)$, and $(1-\theta)^2$ respectively, yielding the trinomial distribution over the group sizes $(x,y,z)$:
$$P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)=\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}\theta^{2x}[2\theta(1-\theta)]^{y}(1-\theta)^{2z}
$$
for $x, y ,z\ge 0$ and $x+y+z=n$.
I want to find the MLE of $\theta$, and determine the asymptotic distribution $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)
$$

---

My work:

Note that the log-likelihood function is that
$$
l(\theta)=n\log n!-\sum\log(X_i!Y_i!Z_i!)+2\sum X_i (\log \theta)+\sum Y_i \log(2\theta(1-\theta))+2\sum Z_i (\log \theta)
$$
Then
$$
\frac{d l(\theta)}{d\theta}=2\sum X_i \frac 1 \theta+\sum Y_i\frac{2(1-2\theta)}{2\theta(1-\theta)}+2\sum Z_i\frac 1 \theta=0
$$
Then
$$
\hat{\theta}_n=\frac{2\bar{X}+\bar{Y}+2\bar{Z}}{2(\bar{X}+\bar{Y}+\bar{Z})}=\frac{n+\bar{X}+\bar{Z}}{2n}
$$
where $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ and $\bar{Y}$, $\bar{Z}$ are similar defined.

But how to get the asymptotic distribution of
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)=\sqrt{n}(\frac{2n-\bar{Y}}{2n}-\theta)
$$

Comment: Asymptotic distributions of MLE are well-known (characterize by the Fisher information matrix). Do you want to derive it by hand here ? 
You can further simplify your expression using that $X + Y  + Z = n$.

Comment: @Pohoua Yes, I want to obtain it by hand.

Comment: @Pohoua Do you mean $\bar{X}+\bar{Y}+\bar{Z}=n$?

Comment: Yes. Both numerator and denominator of the ratio of your last equation can simplify.

Comment: Pohoua's comments gives you the main hint you need to get started to answer. What specifically about constructing the asymptotic distribution is giving you trouble? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Pohoua But how to get the chi-square after this simplified?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this from scratch is to recognise that it's actually a $Bin(2,\theta)$, so that the sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is the mean number of successes, $\bar Y+2\bar X$ and the MLE is $(\bar Y+2\bar X)/n$. But that might be regarded as cheating

Comment: @Hermi I think then that the asymptotic distribution is normal (not chi squared) and it follows directly from the central limit theorem.

Comment: @Hermi (I think that the numerator can be further simplified to $2n - \bar Y$, this may help to see how to apply the central limit theorem).

Comment: @Pohoua But there will be a term $\sqrt{n}\times 2$.

Comment: Well the central limit theorem states that $\sqrt{n} (\bar X - \mu) \overset{D}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2)$, from that you can easily get the asymptotic distribution of your estimator. 
Although, now I think there could be a mistake in the expression of $\hat \theta$ which you gave. Are you sure of it ?